# Alloc memory and make it stay there after quit

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm working on a kernel module. Long story short: I need to allocate some memory and make it stay there after the module is unloaded. Is it possible? How?

Please keep in mind I'm not asking if that is a good idea. I have my reasons, which are good.

Comment: I'm not sure if it requires some special stuff...  But here's my suggestion: Make that pointer global and extern it in other files where you want to use that memory?

Comment: @user9000 that memory will be marked as executable and it will hold it's own code, which will be called from the syscall table.

Comment: The memory allocated to the process that allocates it is released after the process is terminated. If your program exits, there is no way to salvage its memory. Use files to share data, maybe.

Comment: @erbdex That is true for userspace, but I'm talking about kernelspace. Does that rule apply there too?

Comment: i am not sure. Are you sure you cannot- 1. Use files. 2. Use IPC?

Comment: @erbdex Yes, I'm sure. That memory won't be referenced from anywhere else apart from the syscall table itself.

Comment: Why don't use one separate module for that? All the data will there while your module can be removed and inserted again. Moreover you can compile it into the kernel and will be looking like you store pointer in the kernel.

Comment: @Michael not possible. I could give you the long version of the story, but the result is that I need to create a stub, mark it as executable memory, fill it with some code and unload my module. No further modules can stay loaded. The only reference to that memory segment would be the syscall table.

Comment: @alexandernst Ok, but the second module is not loaded - it is compiled-in. Like file system driver or video drivers. Will it be ok? Otherwise if "compiling-in the second module"-way is not possible, then what is about creating your own system call, which do the things you need?

Comment: So you're trying to build a rootkit? Messing with the syscall table is generally frowned upon, but if you're also combining it with unloading the module which did it, a rootkit is all I can think of.

Comment: @KristofProvost I'd love to see if the downvote is yours... Anyways, https://github.com/alexandernst/procmon That's what I'm working on. Not a rootkit at all, as you can see. The reason I ask for this question? https://github.com/alexandernst/procmon/issues/31

Comment: It certainly was. You really should add that link to the question, if only to give us a little more context. (I *really* dislike reading things like 'I have my reasons'. It implies we wouldn't approve of those reasons, or that they're really bad reasons.)

Comment: @KristofProvost Maybe I should have added it, but last time I asked something about Procmon, I just got replies explaining why I'm wasting my time and why I should be patching ```pref/audit``` instead. And I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: I was going to point to ktap (https://github.com/ktap/ktap) actually... It's a DTrace like tool, which looks like it might make it into the mainline kernel at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy enough to do, really. All you have to do is dynamically allocate the memory in the module init function and they fail to deallocate it in the exit function. In other words, create a deliberate memory leak.

You'll need to be careful during the init though, to avoid doing the allocation (and syscall table patching) multiple times. I'd strongly suggest not doing this, and only keeping your monitoring code active as long as the module is loaded. Keeping it active afterwards means you have the multiple-loads problem, and it's also going to surprise the users of your module.

Comment: Oh, I really didn't thought it would be that easy :P So, the general rule that allocated memory by a process get's cleared when the process dies doesn't apply to the kernel/kernel modules, right?

Comment: Correct. No handholding in the kernel ;)